# Laravel 4 packages register "app:after" filter

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am developing a package for laravel 4 ("workbench"), and i would like to bind the "app:after" filter, to manipulate the http response.

Does anybody know how could i take control over the "app:after" filter within my package? is it possible at all?

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write a [`ServiceProvider`](http://laravel.com/docs/packages#service-providers), you can use the `$this->app->after` method inside the ServiceProvider's `register` method.

The users who pull in your package only need to register your serviceprovider in the `app.providers` config array.

Comment: thanks for your answer. do you know how can i set response headers within that method? $callback doesn't contain the response object.

Comment: Like this:

    $this->app->after(function ($request, $response) {
        $reponse->header('Content-Type', $value);
    }